# Can't install localstack on freshly reformatted ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, localstack

I'm having a hard time installing localstack. This is on a freshly reformatted ubuntu pc. I keep getting this error:

```
(test which virtualenv || pip install --user virtualenv) && 
(test -e .venv || virtualenv .venv) && 
(test ! -e requirements.txt || (. .venv/bin/activate; pip -q install -r requirements.txt) && 
. .venv/bin/activate; PYTHONPATH=. exec python localstack/services/install.py testlibs)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13119c7910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/airspeed/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13119c7b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/airspeed/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13119c7cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/airspeed/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13119c7e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/airspeed/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13119c7f50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/airspeed/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement airspeed==0.5.5.dev20160812 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for airspeed==0.5.5.dev20160812 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
```

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: it looks a little bit like a connection problem... can you ping canonical webservers?

Answer (score 2):

After much digging, I was finally able to make it work.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.meeps.site/2018/11/setting-up-localstack-and-creating-sqs-queues-and-sns-topics) really helpful!

So instead of installing it directly to my pc, I decided to use
docker.

```
git clone https://github.com/localstack/localstack.git
cd path/to/localstack
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to run

```
$> localstack start
```

which required docker and docker-compose.

To run natively, you need to use:

```
$> localstack start --host
```

I have written step by step blogs to install and run natively. You can refer : https://medium.com/@baksh12shad/how-to-install-localstack-natively-on-ubuntu-18-04-step-by-step-ca344b7b7d78